# iPad Info.plist not converting to binary

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, binary, info.plist

This question is little out of the box so please bear with me with this one. I am trying to build an iPad Application and release it to App store, however I am getting this issue of Info.plist being build as XML format than Binary. I sense that in the build settings of the XCode that you can keep the aspect of Info.plist either as XML or binary. Although I have kept it as binary, but I keep getting my Info.plist as in XML format, this I confirmed by looking at the .app Extracted version and still the Info.plist tends to be in binary format. If I tend to manually change the Info.plist file in Command Line as plutil -convert binary1 Info.plist, then the code signature changes apparently and then iTunes gives me an app signature error. However, without changing that I do get it in iTunes and uploaded on iPad with no error's, but got response from App store that the content of Info.plist should be in binary format. Any help here would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Shawn

Answer (score 1):

So I finally got the answer towards my own question. The application have some shell scripts that wrap code signature and revisions around, where in revision shell it utilized PBuddyList to write the content off. I assume it was changing the content back to XML format after writing the content, and then code signing and zipping the content towards IPA file.

So a simple addition to the line of plutil -convert binary1 "Info.plist" does the job.

Thank you again and hope this helps someone in near future.

Shawn